# Displaying a Hyperlink on a h:inputTextarea

Tags: java, jsf, hyperlink, textarea

I'm trying to display a hyperlink clickable in a inputtextarea
is that possible? If no, how could I do it without the inputtextarea but same effects as a textarea?

Comment: i've got 2 text areas. the one the user types stuff, and the one that shows what he wrote(typing disabled). so, i guess only the inputtextarea that typing is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with a HTML `<textarea>` element, so the JSF `<h:inputTextarea>` already can't do much for you.

If you don't need it to be editable, just use a `<h:outputText escape="false">` to not escape HTML.

```xml
<h:outputText value="#{bean.value}" escape="false" />
```

Bring in some CSS if necessary to make it look like a textarea, e.g.

```css
.someClass {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Be careful with [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) however when it concerns user-controlled input! Running the [`Jsoup#clean()`](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) on the input may be helpful in this.

But if you need it to be editable, then you basically need a HTML editor component. The standard JSF component library doesn't ship with such a component. Head to a 3rd party component library like PrimeFaces which has a [`<p:editor>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf).

Comment: it isn't possible with textarea?

Comment: No. I would otherwise have answered it :)

Comment: I thought so, but wanted to make sure ;)